# Fix circular dependency in arithmetic class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, circular-dependency, crtp

I have a set of classes implementing the curiously recurring template pattern. However, the trick is that the base class needs to return instances of the subclasses. Here's an example:

```
template <typename SubType>
class ArithmeticBase
{
public:
    template <typename OtherType>
    const Addition operator+(const OtherType &other)
        {return Addition(get_subclass(), other);}

    // ...
    // Operators for subtraction, multiplication, division, ...

private:
    const SubType &get_subclass() const
        {return *static_cast<const SubType*>(this);}
};

template <typename OperatorType1, typename OperatorType2>
class Addition : ArithmeticBase<Addition<OperatorType1, OperatorType2>>
{
public:
    Addition(const OperatorType1 &op1, const OperatorType2 &op2)
        : op1(op1)
        , op2(op2)
    {}

private:
    const OperatorType1 &op1;
    const OperatorType2 &op2;
};

// ...
// Additional classes for subtraction, multiplication, division, ...
```

Compiling this fails because the `Addition` class is not defined before it's used in the `ArithmeticBase` class:

```
arithmetic.cpp:6:8: error: unknown type name 'Addition'
        const Addition operator+(const OtherType &other)
              ^
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: make it a non-member friend operator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could forward declare `Addition` before the base class.

```
template <typename OperatorType1, typename OperatorType2>
class Addition;
template <typename SubType>
class ArithmeticBase
{
...
};
```

This allows the compiler to know there is a type `Addition` that exists before it is defined.

Comment: That's not a correct forward declaration of a class template.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that a return type could be an incomplete type.

Comment: @Joel: It can be in a declaration, but not in a definition.  See JKor's answer.

Comment: @BenVoigt Hmm, then why does this compile fine? https://gist.github.com/anonymous/039e630dd66bc7d0eb43

Comment: @Joel: Oh right, it's because the instantiation of the template function occurs much later than the function template definition.

Comment: @BenVoigt Ah, I see now

Answer (score 2):

Or use non-member form declared after `Addition`:

```
template <typename OperatorType1, typename OperatorType2>
class Addition;

template <typename SubType>
class ArithmeticBase
{
public:

     template <typename OneType, typename OtherType>
     friend const Addition<OneType, OtherType> operator+(const ArithmeticBase<OneType>& one, const OtherType &other);

private:
    const SubType &get_subclass() const
    {
        return *static_cast<const SubType*>(this);
    }
};

class ArithmeticType : public ArithmeticBase < ArithmeticType > {};

template <typename OperatorType1, typename OperatorType2>
class Addition : ArithmeticBase<Addition<OperatorType1, OperatorType2>>
{
public:
    Addition(const OperatorType1 &op1, const OperatorType2 &op2)
        : op1(op1)
        , op2(op2)
    {}

private:
    const OperatorType1 &op1;
    const OperatorType2 &op2;
};


template <typename OneType, typename OtherType>
const Addition<OneType, OtherType> operator+(const ArithmeticBase<OneType>& one, const OtherType &other)
{
    return Addition<OneType, OtherType>(one.get_subclass(), other);
}

int main()
{
    ArithmeticType a, b;
    a + b;
}
```

Comment: The original restricts the left-hand argument to instantiations of `ArithmeticBase`, yours does not.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to forward declaring the `Addition` class (as bhzag's answer shows) you'll need to move the definition of `operator+` to after the definition the Addition class.  Otherwise you'll get an error on the next line.

Make sure the definition is in the header file.  If it isn't, you'll get linker errors.